# iOS UIView flickers on screen rotation

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview

I have a UIView that contains a search bar and an image. Turns out that when I rotate the device the background flickers like this:

[image]

Not sure how to avoid this flickering. If I remove the UIView container altogether this flickering stops happening.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was creating my view as follows:

```
let myView = UIView()
```

I then set up the constraints.

However, after I created the view with the frame the flickering no longer happens:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: myFrame)
```

Even if I tried creating the view with a `.zero` frame, the flickering still happened.
I tried investigating what happens under the hood and find out the reason for this flickering but didn't find much, if someone knows it would be great to know!.
Thanks!